# how to add Number of document in new column , trouh SQL (Oracle data )

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table “web_ord” with columns( and some data for example) :

```
DATE    CD_ITRY  CD_CUST CD_ADDR RND      CD_ITEM        QTY
29.03.2014  194 212382  36  3   60000998    20
29.03.2014  194 212382  36  3   60000999    20
29.03.2014  194 212382  36  3   60000780    20
29.03.2014  194 203292  1   1   60000998    20
29.03.2014  194 203292  1   1   60000999    20
29.03.2014  194 203292  1   1   60000780    20
29.03.2014  194 203292  5   1   60000998    20
29.03.2014  194 203292  5   1   60000999    20
29.03.2014  194 203292  5   1   60000780    20
29.03.2014  194 222171  10  2   60000998    20
29.03.2014  194 222171  10  2   60000999    20
29.03.2014  194 222171  10  2   60000780    20
```

When I use `select from g_web_ord`, I need  a column with number of document (which not exist in table), Referring three columns `cd_cust||cd_addr||rnd`.
Is it  possible ( some function or with SQL ), to get some kind of number ( as number of document) , in additional column 
which will give me unique number for every distinct  concatenate column of `cd_cust||cd_addr||rnd`
I try function :  `count (*) over (partition by CD_CUST||CD_ADDR||RND)` 
but that will give me the same number if I have exact number of rows for concatenate columns .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    try 

 `select dbms_random.value(1,5) from dual`

    it will generate a random number
```

Comment: that will give me different number for itch row, what i need is a number that will be the same for all row's that referr for  unique concatenate three columns.What I meen , if I have 15 rows with one unique concatenate (CD_CUST||CD_ADDR||RND)) , to get the same number for itch row,and for the other concatenate (CD_CUST||CD_ADDR||RND)), another number....ets..   :)